# Can't access search catalog objects through Square sandbox api

Tags: square, square-connect

I can't access search catalog objects through sandbox api. I am getting error as:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "category": "INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR",
            "code": "SANDBOX_NOT_SUPPORTED",
            "detail": "This endpoint does not support sandbox calls."
        }
    ]
}
```

I am not sure if I'm missing something.

Please help if anyone had found the solution. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Square Catalog API is not supported in [sandbox mode](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/using-sandbox) at this time. The only way to search catalog objects is through production mode.